# How to use wigle.net API

Tags: api

I have to make a query to the Wigle's API, but I didn't find the API documentation (https://wigle.net/wiki/index.cgi?HomePage).
I have a list of Access Point's SSID and I have to interrogate Wigle in order to know the location of all the SSIDs. 
Now I'm able to do this:

```
 http://WiGLE.net/gpsopen/gps/GPSDB/confirmquery?longrange1=12.4952&longrange2=12.5434&latrange1=41.8973&latrange2=41.9136&simple=true
```

that return all the APs of an area.
If I want to know the location of an SSID without give a bounding box (lat,lon) what kind of query I have to do?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this python class https://code.activestate.com/recipes/578637-wigle-wifi-geolocation/ and I solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the official WiGLE api at https://api.wigle.net for starters.

There's interactive Swagger documentation at https://api.wigle.net/swagger to help you get started.